# PHP detect browser can use webgl

Tags: php, browser, webgl

Does anyone know how to check in php if a browser has webgl or not and display a true or false value?  I know if I use:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

displays all the attributes/features of a browser, but does it do webgl?  Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: it seems it would be best to check with client side code (javascript

Comment: @AhmedDaou no way to do this in php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript to check it for you, then you can make it send the value to php.

JavaScript:

```
if (Modernizr.webgl) { 
  var webgl = "True";
  window.location.href = "myphpfile.php?webgl =" + webgl ;
} else { 
  var webgl = "False";
  window.location.href = "myphpfile.php?webgl =" + webgl ;
}
```

PHP:

```
$value = $_GET['name'];
```

Comment: Any way to do it without adding modernizr library?  I wanted to keep it as slim as possible?